# Axios Post and props value

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vue-component, laravel-5.7

i´ve got a little problem with my Laravel / Vue Component. I tried to do a Form Component in which you can just define the path and the category as static variables.
Now i want to access it in axios.post but its not working:

create.blade.php (Backend Site for creating something)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
@include('includes.header')
<body>
    <div id="app" class="wrapper">
        <nav-component></nav-component>
        <form-component kategorie ='achievement' senden='/achievement'></form-component>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Vue Component for form-component:

```
export default {
    props: ['kategorie', 'senden'],

    data: function() {
        return {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        text: '',
        category: this.kategorie,
        errors: new Errors()
        }
    },

    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            axios.post({data:this.senden}, {
                title: this.title,
                description: this.description,
                text: this.text,
                category: this.category

            })
                .then(this.onSuccess)
                .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors));
        },
        onSuccess(response) {

            alert(response.data.message);

            this.title = '';
            this.description = '';
            this.text = '';
        }
    },

    http:{
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    }
}
```

The Errors class which contains hasOwnProperty

```
 class Errors {
        constructor() {
            this.errors = {}
        }
        get(field) {

            if (this.errors[field]) {
                return this.errors[field][0];
            }

        }

        record(errors) {
            this.errors = errors;
        }

        clear(field) {
            delete this.errors[field];
        }

        has(field) {
            return this.errors.hasOwnProperty(field);
        }

        any() {
            return Object.keys(this.errors).length > 0;
        }
    }
```

Laravel Controller store

```
$this->validate(request(), [
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'text' => 'required',
            'category' => 'required'
        ]);

        Achievement::forceCreate([
            'title' => request('title'),
            'description' => request('description'),
            'text' => request('text'),
            'category' => request('category')
        ]);

        return ['message' => 'Erfolg erstellt'];
```

How could i do that properly?
Like this ill get a 405 (Method Not Allowed) and  Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined" error

Comment: Could you attach the whole stacktrace? If you get 405 error - you are either making a wrong request either your server code is wrong. In both way it's not clear what you're doing since you posted little of code.

Comment: What exactly do you need? The Controller Code? Cause its not really much more Vue/JS Code in there

Comment: 1) stacktrace. 2) code where you `have.hasOwnProperty`. 3) Server code that should process your request

Comment: Ill added the code which you need. Stacktrace is comming in a second.

Comment: app.js:285 POST http://localhost:8000/achievements/[object%20Object] 405 (Method Not Allowed)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:285
xhrAdapter @ app.js:119
dispatchRequest @ app.js:724
Promise.then (async)
request @ app.js:531
Axios.(anonymous function) @ app.js:551
wrap @ app.js:984
onSubmit @ app.js:1877
submit @ app.js:36503
invoker @ app.js:39122
fn._withTask.fn._withTask @ app.js:38907

Comment: Are you using webpack to assemble app.js? Please enable source maps and attach source code (not built one). `app.js:551` tells me nothing. You should have instead like `yourComponentName.vue:55` and also attach that component code that throws an exception

Comment: Yeah ill do use webpack

Comment: The problem has to do with the props element. If ill hardcode it like /achievements instead of the prop element in axios.post({data:this.senden} its working.

Comment: Maybe theres a better way to tell the axios where to post at